# Standalone Apache Spark - what to put as slave ip and port?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to start a Apache Spark cluster on my local MacBook Pro. I started the master with:

```
myMachine$ ./start-master.sh
```

then in the logger, I have this:

```
14/08/30 10:25:38 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://myMachine.local:7077
```

Now I need to start one slave:

```
myMachine$./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://IP:PORT
```

What should be the proper IP and PORT here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just telling this slave where to find the master. 
It should work using `myMachine.local` or even `localhost` for the 'IP' (I don't believe it really needs an actual IP address, a hostname should be fine) and `7077` for the port -- that is, just mimic what was printed out when you started the master.

```
myMachine$./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://myMachine.local:7077
```

Comment: Since it took me a while to figure it out I'll point out that if all you want is a Scala console to play with some examples on your laptop you may not actually *need* a cluster. You can just run `./bin/spark-shell --master local[4]` and use `:load` to load your Scala code -- the 4 is the number of threads, which you can adjust. If you check the [Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) you'll see that you can even put the name of a jar at the end of this command to have it added to the classpath.

Comment: Thanks Spiro! I set the worker as you suggested and the master seems to find it. However, the Java WordCount example still doesn't work. The following are error messages, what am I missing here? Thanks a lot!  "WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Failed to connect to master org.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid master URL: spark://spark://myMachine.local:7077 at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$.toAkkaUrl(Master.scala:777)" ... "WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory"

Comment: @Edamame: Do the other examples run? The smoking gun is that the URL in the error message has a repeated scheme `spark://spark://` -- are you sure you didn't accidentally repeat it in your spark-class command? Or did you use any other commands involving the host and port?

Comment: Thanks Spiro! Yes, you are right, I put spark://spark://myMachine.local:7077 in the Java VM argument. I fixed it and the job MapReduce job starts! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

After starting the master, go to

```
  localhost:8080
```

There will be your master ip and port informations like

```
Spark Master at spark://yourip:7077
```